# problems with global variables

Tags: php, include, global-variables

I have a problem with include pages in PHP. Picture shows what I want to do. I want to include in my index.php page horizontal and vertical menu. But now I can include only one of them. In global.php there are database name, password, and variable which define what language I'm using now.
I included with all derictives: include, include_once, require, require_once. Nothing helps. What can you propose me to do? Thanx!

[image]

**EDIT:**

Here is my code:

Index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>KUSS</title>
<link href="styles/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="main_border">
<?php 
    include_once ("modules/php/mainMenu.php"); 
?>

<? include_once ("modules/php/vertMenu.php"); ?><!--Head-->


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

global.php

```
<?php
// All global variables MUST be defines here

//representing current language
$gl_Lang = "UKR";       

//current horizontal menu click
$gl_MaimMenuChoice;     
//current vertical sub menu click
$gl_SubMenuChoice;

$gl_dbName = "127.0.0.1";
$gl_UserName = "user1";
$gl_Password = "12345";
$gl_adminDatabase = "admin";

?>
```

---

makeHoriz.php and makeVert.php identical except one read from db and shows rows and second cols

```
<?php
function MakeLeftVMenu($tableName, $levelID, $parentName)
{
    include_once ("modules/php/globals.php");

    //connect to db or die)
    $db = mysql_connect($gl_dbName, $gl_UserName, $gl_Password ) or die ("Unable to connect");

    //to prevenr ????? symbols in unicode - utf-8 coding
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");

    //select database
    mysql_select_db($gl_adminDatabase, $db);
    $sql = "SELECT " .$gl_Lang. ", Link FROM ". $tableName." WHERE LevelID = ".$levelID. " AND ParentName = '". $parentName."'";
    echo $sql;
    //execute SQL-query
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    //read data to array
    $myRow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    //print it to screen into the table
    do
    {
        echo "<tr><h3><a href=".trim($myRow['Link']).">". trim($myRow[$gl_Lang]) ."</a></h3></tr>";


    }while($myRow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    //close database  = very inportant
    mysql_close($db);
}
?>
```

Comment: What error do you see when including both?

Comment: OMG, THE PICTURE! Where's the +2 button?

Comment: +infinity for awesome picture!

Comment: @porcupine: instead of pictures - some code and file structure would be better. Perhaps you made a typo, or the file is not there.

Comment: On another note don't get confused as labeling that a global variable, as there is a variable type of global in php.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `horizonal_menu.php` and `vertical_menu.php` are both including `global.php`, you should make sure both of them are using `require_once`.  If that is the case, you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Id also add that IMO global should only be included by the overall layout (ie. index.php or whatever page). Then that layout should take care of including all the "components" like the menus.

Comment: require_once is a crutch. The op should make sure he isn't writing senseless code. that's all

Answer (score 0):

If all pages are going to have a horizontal/vertical menu you might go to the extent of creating a header.php that includes horizontal/vertical menu and the global.php.

Answer (score 0):

Do the Menu pages every get called on their own?  eg do you ever go in the browser to http://mywebsite.com/horizontalmenu.php ?  If not then it is safe to assume that any included files needed by horizontalmenu.php will be available from a previously included php file, or you can use require_once for all includes.

Eg

Index.php

```
include('global.php');
include('horizontalmenu.php');
include('verticalmenu.php');
```

horiztontalmenu.php

```
 //No include statments as it is being included by Index.php which
 //has provided access to all global.php functions and variables.
```

Alternatively if you use require_once for every single require or include statement you should avoid the problem.