# PHP include file. Showing error file not found

Tags: php, include

I am using include function and it is giving errors. That is file not found.
In the root directory I have - index.php and config.php

**index.php** includes **config.php** and has some other data.

**config.php** has database details and includes function/function.php

There is a folder user and it has a file **calculate.php**
in **calculate.php** I have included AJAX functionality and a file is loaded in it on AJAX call. File is **cal2.php** and it is located in **user** folder.
Now this, **cal2.php** has a include function for **config.php** like:

> include "../config.php";

When this **cal2.php** is loaded from **calculate.php**

**function/function.php** file is not loaded. It shows file not found for **function/function.php**

So, file structure is:

- root
- /index.php
- /config.php
- /user/calculate.php
- /user/cal2.php
- /function/function.php

How to proceed and not have function.php include error for cal2.php

Comment: how are you loading function/function.php, in cal2.php? please post that code.

Comment: 2 rules to follow. 1. **Always** post actual code. 2. **Always** post exact and complete error message.

Comment: As for your problem - it's easy. Just use existing path. there is no `/user/function/` folder in your system.

Comment: Actually, it isn't that easy. Following the instructions the OP has given for creating the filesystem to the letter and using 100% relative includes exactly as described does not cause a problem to occur. It works 100% a-ok without changing a single thing.

Comment: @Shabbyrobe the path can be relative or absolute, but first of all it should be **correct,** pointing to the existing file. So, the OP have to determine that path first. A static one. And only then start building it dynamically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change config.php to use an absolute path to functions.php. If you have PHP 5.3 or greater, do it like this:

```
include __DIR__.'/functions/functions.php';
```

If you are still using PHP 5.2 (or, god forbid, something earlier), you can do it this way:

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
include $dir.'/functions/functions.php';
```

The __FILE__ magic constant always contains the value of the current PHP file name, so the `dirname(__FILE__)` call will give you the full filesystem path of the current script.

Comment: it will help include functions into config, but won't help include config into everything else. Don't use relative paths. use absolute ones.

Comment: `__DIR__` and `dirname(__FILE__)` *are* absolute paths

Comment: It's still relative, silly. formally absolute, but it's built from the relative position from the current file. move that file somewhere else and your *relative* path would fail. That's why an absolute path should be always used, based on some constant.

Answer (score 2):

Use absolute path to include file:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/function/function.php'
```

Comment: Using `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` is better as it is not dependent on the server environment in order to work.

Comment: @Shabbyrobe it isn't better. It won't help at all

Comment: This doesn't work when executing the php script from a command line (for example from cron).

Answer (score -1):

All problems here

```
/user/cal2.php
/function/function.php
```

you need to include such a way:

```
include('../config.php');
```

BUT I had this problem to, and I propose you to include files in the header of each page. Config you must inckude in the header of each page.

Read this, think it helps:

[problems with global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128166/problems-with-global-variables)