# Require a class in CodeIgniter subfolder?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this structure

```
controllers
- base.php
\ subfolder
  - home.php
```

in `home.php` I want to call

```
require("../base.php")
```

but it gives me an error message saying the file was not found. On the same folder it works.

Is there a way to get it working on the subfolder?

Comment: I am testing on Windows, but I will deploy to a Linux server

Comment: run in code in linux or windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter is executed from within `index.php` script and paths of `require` function are resolved based on `index.php` path. For example if you would put `test.php` in CodeIgniter root folder and then you would call `require './test.php'` from your controller then the `test.php` would be included without a problem.

To answer the question we need php magic constant `__DIR__` which is always set to current script folder. The answer is:

```
require __DIR__."/../base.php";
```

called from within `home.php`.

Edit: And platform independent solution would be:

```
require __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."..".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."base.php";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use full path:

```
$origin = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$home = $origin. "/controllers/home.php";
require($home);
```

But I understand that It's a pain in the butt over a long term, but It's a solution. I have never had a problem like that before.

But maybe this could be of more help? [PHP include file. Showing error file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482253/php-include-file-showing-error-file-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
require("/<full dir path>/base.php");
```

Another tip - sometimes in windows (not helpful if you plan to deploy on Linux) is sometimes you have to escape '\\' by using double slashes.

If that doesn't work, it is probably a permissions problem.

Edit: use this to get your include path:

```
echo ini_get('include_path');
```

That will tell you which path to use.

Comment: The problem is that paths in PHP are always relative to the first file path, in this case home.php. So you have to include the dir 'controllers'. Depends on the config on PHP and/or the server too though.

Comment: @BrunoLM Don't forget to select an answer for you question ;) Happy Friday!

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, the accepted answer is correct in that `require` (and similar function) paths are based on the location of index.php. However, CodeIgniter has very helpful constants defined in index.php that allow you to create paths to various parts of your application.

The `APPPATH` constant would be perfect for pointing towards a controller/library/etc.

```
require APPPATH . 'controllers/base.php';
```

An even better solution would be to create a base controller in the form of `application/core/MY_Controller.php`. You can then extend your controllers using `MY_Controller` without the need to require any files. [Check out Phil's article about Base Controllers.](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY)